# UIResponder chain not working in UIButton action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uiresponder

I have a uibutton in child view controller that its action  needs to be called in parent view controller.
this is my code

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      btn.addTarget(nil, action: Selector(("onBtnTap")), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
 }

class ParrentViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
   }

  func onBtnTap(sender: Any) {
    print("Hey, I am Parent VC ")
  }
}
```

when i tap button the method onBtnTap  not called and no crash occurred .

Comment: why you are not tried base viewcontroller concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of Parent in Child to achieve this, here's how:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    let parentVC = ParentViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btn.addTarget(parentVC, action: #selector(parentVC.onBtnTap(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @objc func onBtnTap(sender: Any) {
        print("Hey, I am Parent VC ")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create the `parentVC` outside the function scope. I've updated check again.